# I'd like to make a wireless charging pad

Tags: coil, wireless-charging

I would like to implement a wireless charging system as my graduation project.

The topology to be used is likely to use the "SS compensation" topology.

The problem is, we have to design the transmitter and receiver pads for wireless charging. I'm looking for the material to make this, but I can't see it.

I want to make it circular in a form called Spiral or Planar. Do you have any data I can refer to?

And the picture I add at the bottom is the circuit diagram I want to make.[image]

Comment: What on earth is a "reward inductor" or "reward capacitor"?

Comment: Maybe series-series topology

Comment: What is your target impedance?

Comment: Target is a battery pack. How do I check my equivalent impedance?